# Laravel 5.4 Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

Im trying to create login form and its controller but when i try to login it doesnt work can any one help me i'm very new in laravel.

here is my form

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-7">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised btn-block ">Sign In</button>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
    </form>
```

and here is my route

```
Route::get('/login', 'loginController@create');
Route::post('/login', 'loginController@store');
```

and my loginController is

```
class loginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'destroy']);
    }

   public function create(){

       return view('pages.admin.login');
   }


    public function store(){

       if(! auth()->attempt(request(['email', 'password']))){
            return back()->withErrors([
                'message' => 'Please check your credentials'
            ]);
        }

        return redirect('/home');
    }


}
```

My user modal is

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'fname','oname','lname', 'email', 'phone','password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Please where i'm i doing wrong on these, when i entered email and password as my credential it just refresh and back to login page

Comment: Please add error message

Comment: it doesn't throw an error

Answer (score 0):

[`auth()->attempt()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php#L361) requires an array, you're sending the return value of request() as a single argument, may that be it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your attempt function should be like:

```
if(Auth::attempt( ['email'=> $request['email'],'password' => $request['password'] ])
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'example@gmail' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `example@gmail` = and `bxndbnbsd` is null limit 1)

Comment: it give me that error even i have the email and password filds

Comment: clearly the query isn't right, notice the sql query its saying where example@gmail =  instead of email=....

Comment: why the store() doesn't have the request object inside? store(Request $request) ?

Comment: I pass them and and when i enter email and pasword it refresh then back to login page but if i redirect by change the redirect->back(); with a valid page it goes to that page

Comment: do this just to make sure
Route::post('/login', 'loginController@store')->name('login);
and in the form:
action="{{route('login')}}"

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like this with `Request` facade.

```
  public function store(Request $request){

   if(! auth()->attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']))){
        return back()->withErrors([
            'message' => 'Please check your credentials'
        ]);
    }

    return redirect('/home');
    }
```

Comment: Stil it do the same, i change and modifying it but still the same it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Add these on top of `LoginController`

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

and modify your `store` method

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;

    if (! Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication Failed...
        return back()->withErrors([
            'message' => 'Please check your credentials'
        ]);
    }

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Also remove `password` from `$hidden` in your `User` Model.

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'remember_token',
];
```

Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php artisan make:auth and laravel will produce everything needed for a login including the controller and then you can go into your resource and edit to make it look how you imagined.

This is what my login controller looks like after using php artisan make:auth

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```